# colorbox iframe and MVC redirection on post

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, colorbox

I have added my colorbox js and css file through MVC bundle and use it on my layout page.When the  page is render on browser the url of colorbox image/loading image get 404 error. This is because the url on console is  http://www.websitename.com/bundle/loading_png.png. Actual link should be 
http://www.websitename.com/content/loading_png.png

Comment: iFrame in 2016 ? Why not use one of the nicest modal dialog plugins ? Bootstrap modal dialog, jQuery ui etc ?

Comment: we are using color box, and color box internally provides Iframe to perform request action